Data Validation Dependent Drop Down List Error With Table
What I am trying to do:
I am trying to add a dependent drop down list via VBA.
Problem:
When I try to step through the code I get an error at the .add line
Sub TaskNoValidation(InputTable As ListObject)
    
    'Data Validation application
    With InputTable.ListColumns("Task No").DataBodyRange.Validation
        .Delete

        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=INDIRECT(""Task_List[""&LEFT(C14&"" "",FIND("" "",C14&"" "")-1)&""]"")"
        '=INDIRECT("Task_List["&LEFT(C14&" ",FIND(" ",C14&" ")-1)&"]")
        
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Task Not Found"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "Note:  The task number entered does not match any tasks numbers assigned to the project in the project database.  Please email Bridge Department Admin Assistant with the information to be added."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub


What I have tried:
When I attempt to add the following data validation formula to D14 (Also first data cell from column 2 of a table) and C14 is empty I get an error that the formula evaluates to an error.
=INDIRECT("Task_List["&LEFT(C14,FIND(" ",C14)-1)&"]")

I originally thought it was evaluating to an error because it could not find a space so I changed it to:
=INDIRECT("Task_List["&LEFT(C14&" ",FIND(" ",C14&" ")-1)&"]")

However, if C14 has its intended information, I do not get an error when creating the data validation.  Further more when I then delete the contents of C14, the data validation drop down list continues to work with the equivalent of all all results.
Question
How do I get the Data Validation List Formula added through VBA?
Update
I have a work around but I m scratching my head still as there might be a different way.  My work around is to store whatever is in C14 into a temporary variable, then populate C14 with the first entry from  the list of values that could be in C14.  Apply the data validation.  And finally return C14 to its initial value.
Sub TaskNoValidation(InputTable As ListObject)
    
Dim InitialValue As Variant
Dim loPNL As ListObject
    
    Set loPNL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Numbers").ListObjects("Project_Number_List")
    
    InitialValue = InputTable.DataBodyRange(1, 1)
    InputTable.DataBodyRange(1, 1) = loPNL.DataBodyRange(1, 1)
        
    With InputTable.ListColumns("Task No").DataBodyRange.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        "=INDIRECT(""Task_List[""&LEFT(C14&"" "",FIND("" "",C14&"" "")-1)&""]"")"
        '=INDIRECT("Task_List["&LEFT(C14&" ",FIND(" ",C14&" ")-1)&"]")
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Task Not Found"
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = _
        "Note:  The task number entered does not match any tasks numbers assigned to the project in the project database.  Please email Bridge Department Admin Assistant with the information to be added."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

    InputTable.DataBodyRange(1, 1) = InitialValue
    
End Sub


How does the formula look like, when you add it manually to the validation (not via VBA)?

@Ike That would be the two formulas presented under what I tried.  I placed both those two in Data Validation in the excel ribbon.  They work when there is data in C14, but they toss an error when C14 is empty.

What do you expect when there is no space? Maybe you could show us some sample data and expected result

It seems the workaround you used is the only way. I tested this functionality earlier and have got this conclusion. Nevertheless, can you try to suppress application alerts?

@rotabor how does one do that?  application.alerts = false?

Application.DisplayAlerts = False. Don't forget to set it to True on exit.
